# Does current Bitcoin break in 2038?

Tags: bitcoin-core, block

I've heard about [year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) and I'm worried [I've read](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_hashing_algorithm) about [Bitcoin measuring time with 32 bits](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/72d6469ab4f6db9570e29a901f021178f110ca44/src/primitives/block.h#L27), why aren't developers worried about Y2038P only 15 years away?

Answer (score 2):

Y2038P was about signed integers.

In Bitcoin, [block time is an unsigned integer](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/72d6469ab4f6db9570e29a901f021178f110ca44/src/primitives/block.h#L27), such case doesn't correspond to a Y2038P, but *a Y2107P*.

Thus the numbers are loosely these:

**2^32 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365.25 ~= 136;

1970 + 136 = 2106**

instead of these:

<del>2^32 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365.25 / 2 ~= 68;

1970 + 68 = 2038</del>

Because we will be dead by 2106, it's not current developers task to worry about.